# single word for "request and response dashboard"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, synonyms

I need single word which represent one place request and responses are shown to user

Comment: Your own term *dashboard* sounds pretty good as the "one place" to display requests and responses.

Comment: @Lawrence This is probably for a software (thus my answer). In software development Dashboard usually represents a "Report" (or "Administration" UI) page which can contain any number of widgets. One of them is likely the one that the OP is pursuing. Some companies create an online chat box but it seems the OP needs something more formal like a place to create tickets (for features, products, etc.).

Comment: I'd go with 'transaction'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a lot on sector and context. Most common expressions, that I know of, that do deal with such concept are not single-worded. However one common single word example is:

> [Support](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/support)
>
> *assist, help [...]  maintain  [...] to keep (something) going*

Multiple word examples are:

> [Help-Desk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/help%20desk)
>
> *a group of people who provide help and information usually for electronic or computer problems*

or more exclusively,

> [Issue Tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system)
>
> *An issue tracking system (also ITS, trouble ticket system, support ticket, request management or incident ticket system) is a computer
>   software package that manages and maintains lists of issues,[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/support) as
>   needed by an organization.* (in Wikipedia)

If you are looking for other alternatives (like naming a widget or a place where this activity happens) you can consider:

> [Solicitor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solicitor)
>
> *one that [solicits](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solicits); to approach with a request or plea*

or,

> [Requestor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requestor)
>
> *the act or an instance of asking for something*

Comment: Thank you i will use "Service-Desk". request and response are related to some kind of service so i use your words "Help-Desk". thanx a lot